# What is that ('Z' - 'A')

Tags: java

In Currency.java file there is a line.

```
    private static final int A_TO_Z = ('Z' - 'A') + 1;
```

What means is this? I didn't see this before. What is A_TO_Z's value and why it using 'Z' instead number.

Comment: This is to avoid use of magic numbers. This makes more logical sense about what number it's trying to derive than would use of number literals (which theoretically may change). So while it makes code a little longer, this sort of structure makes code *much* easier to debug.

Comment: `char`s can be treated as `int`s in Java.

Comment: Did you read the [comment above that line](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/Currency.java#161)? It says `number of characters from A to Z`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With this expression you are treating `char`s as `int`s, using character's Unicode value instead of the character itself.

```
'Z' - 'A' + 1
```

Will become

```
90 - 65 + 1 (=26)
```

Comment: It's not ASCII, it's Unicode codepoints (the numeric values are the same for those two characters, but it's an important difference to note).

Comment: @Backslash 0041 hex is 65 decimal.

Answer (score 3):

`'Z'` is a char with an integral value of `90`.
`'A'` is a char with an integral value of `65`.

`90 - 65 + 1 = 26`

Answer (score 2):

Nasty. 'A' is the char literal for ASCII value of A (65 in decimal). 'Z' is 90. So A_TO_Z is 26, the number of letters in the English alphabet.

Comment: It is the number of letters in the *English* alphabet. Big difference. (Also, it assumes ASCII ordering, but I'm pretty sure Java guarantees that, so you are clear at least as far as that goes.)

Comment: Or ASCII definition of the English alphabet.

Answer (score 1):

Characters have numeric values according to their value in the character table. That expression exploits the fact that all the letters form A to Z have consecutive values in the underlying encoding table thus subtracting the first value from the last ( + 1) gives the length of the English alphabet. The actual numerical values are unimportant in this case and the code is more or less self-explainable to the reader. In case the used encoding spreads the letters differently, the expression will become incorrect.